# Unable to ping any external IP from my pod in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ping, azure-aks

I've an AKS cluster running but I cannot ping any external IP from a "simple" container:

```
> kubectl run -it --rm node --image=node:14.15.1-slim -- bash
root@node:/# apt update && apt -y install iputils-ping
root@node:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

The last "PING"-line stalls forever. Any idea what causes the problem? I already added a load balancer because I read that it helped for some people but it didn't solved my issue...

**Update**

I can connect to any IP and the DNS also resolves. So it's fine for the first time. But I'm very interested why I cannot get any response from the ping. I guess something is blocking the ICMP messages.

Comment: Do you have any rules on the NSG of the subnet?

Answer (score -1):

using ping in bash without defining how many times it pings might be causing the stall, try:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -c 3
```

to ping three times